# Input a mean and standard deviation to apply probability distribution across DataFrame Pandas Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, dataframe

I have a series of dates in the future. I would like to use an assumption about standard deviation and mean of a yet-to-be scheduled event to  'forecast' the future probability of that event falling on any given day.  Say I have a Pandas DF with a `min/max` date of `1/8/16` and `2/3/16`.  I currently just running an equal probability over all days (`.037 ...`).

I have it in a dataframe that looks like this (I have filled in the desired `Standard_dev_assisted_probability` manually):

```
Poss_Date   Equal_probability  Standard_dev_assisted_probability

1/8/2016    0.037037            min date in poss date range
1/9/2016    0.037037
1/10/2016   0.037037
1/11/2016   0.037037            -1st dv / two thirds border
1/12/2016   0.037037
1/13/2016   0.037037
1/14/2016   0.037037
1/15/2016   0.037037
1/16/2016   0.037037
1/17/2016   0.037037
...         ...
1/22/2016   0.037037            mean / peak of distribution
...         ...
2/1/2016    .03707              +~1std dev
2/3/2016    0.037037            max date in poss range
```

If we assume that the 'mean' of the future distribution is `1/22/16`,  And the standard dev is 11 days...

Is there a way to plug those in to the Pandas DF and have it spit back out a column with probability?  Obviously, 66% of the probability should then be allocated `+/- 11` days around `1/22`,  with normal distribution/etc.

I'm imaginging in pseudocode it will be something like:

```
df['Probability']=df.applystandarddev(column=dates,mean=1/22,stddv=11)
```

If we don't need to 'account' for the abbreviated period of time past the mean, great.  Obviously there is more time before the mean than after, but I figure that's part of the statistics game that the libraries handle, etc.

Comment: It seems you would identify the distribution. Given your parameter choices, I'm guessing you are thinking a normal distribution? I'd also think exponential, pareto might be reasonable choices as well.

Comment: @David Maust I'd be thrilled to even use a normal distribution to start.  I can't even think of exactly how to do that -

Comment: maybe there is a way to use scipy.norm(index_of_mean,std_dev) and then a sort of probability at the spot of the other indexes method....

Comment: I would think `scipy.stats.distribution.norm.cdf` would do it. Subtract the CDF at the end of the day `day+1` from the CDF at the beginning of the day. That is the probability for the day. In a little bit I'll post an example, unless someone wants to beat me to it.

Comment: It is appreciated greatly.  If it's much easier to implement this using pandas index rather than date objects, or something like that, I think that works just as well.  Also it might allow me to filter out things like weekends if I so chose and possibly not have to adjust any code.  As sort of always calculating the probability on the index rather than the dates might ... keep those things sort of indpendent.  Not sure if that's a half baked thought-  ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking the CDF of a given probability at the end of the day and at the beginning of the day, we are able to find the probability that an event will occur during that day.

Here is an example with a normal distribution.

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import norm

def prob_distribution(day, mean_day, std):
    start_z = float((day - mean_day).days) / std
    end_z = float((day - mean_day).days + 1) / std
    return norm.cdf(end_z) - norm.cdf(start_z)

df['Prob'] = df['Poss_Date'].apply(lambda day: prob_distribution(day, datetime(2016,2,1), 10))
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to ensure that I was passing the func .. a day and a mean_day which are Pandas.Timestamp and a std which was a long.  I suppose the only further features would be a way to filter weekends out, or to try a non normal distribution.  Maybe if I could fit a distribution to some of my data.  hehe.... perhaps that last thing is for another thread altogether.  thanks David.